# Interior of dense set in ultraregular space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a regular Hausdorff topological space without isolated point. We say that $X$ is ultraregular if the following condition holds: for every subset $A \subset X$, such that $A$ and $\complement A$ are both without isolated point, then $A$ (and $\complement A$) are open sets.

Let $A$ be an everywhere dense set (i.e. $\overline A=X$). I would like to prove that the interior $\mathring A$ of $A$ is everywhere dense as well, i.e. $\overline{\mathring A}=X$.

It is not difficult to see that $\mathring A$ is not empty, and that $\mathring A$ is not closed. But I'm not able to prove the stronger fact that $\mathring A$ is everywhere dense.

It could help to know the following fact: if $A$ is a set without isolated point, then $\overline A$ is an open set.

Thank you.

Comment: Just wondering, are there any such spaces? Could you give examples?

Comment: Let $X$ be a regular space without isolated point. Denote by $T_0$ the topology of $X$. It is easy to see that the set of topologies $T$ which are finer than $T_0$ and regular without isolated point is inductive. So we can find a maximal topology, which is finer than $T_0$ and regular without isolated point. We readily see that such topologies are exactly the ultraregular topologies.

Comment: Ok. So there only non-constructive examples? Or also explicit ones?

Comment: I don't know of any explicit ultraregular space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $D$ be a dense subset of $X$, and let $U=\operatorname{int}D$. Let $V=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}U$; then $\operatorname{cl}U$ and $V$ are clopen in $X$, and we wish to show that $V=\varnothing$. Let $E=D\cap V$; note that $\operatorname{int}E=\varnothing$. Clearly $E$ is dense in $V$, which is ultraregular, so $E$ has no isolated points. Let $A=V\setminus E$, and suppose that $p$ is an isolated point of $A$. Then there is a $W$ open in $X$ such that $p\in W\subseteq E\cup\{p\}$. Clearly $W\cap E\ne\emptyset$, so $W\setminus\{p\}$ is a non-empty open subset of $E$, which is impossible. Thus, $A$ has no isolated points, and $E$ is open in $V$ and hence in $X$, which is possible only if $E=\varnothing$ and hence $V=\operatorname{cl}E=\varnothing$.

Probably this is just repeating your argument that $U$ is non-empty, but relativized to $V$.

Comment: Glad to see you, you have been missed!

Comment: Nice seeing you back Brian!! +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was about to answer my own question with something quite similar to this. Indeed the basic (and easy) fact is that any open subspace in an ultraregular space is ultraregular.

Comment: @timofei: It’s always more satisfying to answer one’s own question: I’m glad that you could.